# SQL joins on phone_number where duration is less than 10min and returning only name column

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables; phones and calls. and I am trying to write a SQL query that finds all clients who talked for at least 10 minutes in total. So the 'phone_number' in phones would match with the 'caller' and 'callee' column in calls and we can sum the durations to find which names have at least 10 minute calls.

**phones**

```
name    phone_number
..................
Jack    1234
Lena    3333                                     
Mark    9999                                       
Anna    7582
```

**calls**

```
id  caller  callee  duration
.............................
25  1234    7582    8
7   9999    7582    1
18  9999    3333    4 
2   7582    3333    3
3   3333    1234    1
21  3333    1234    1
```

The query should return only the name column alphabetically.

```
name  
.....
Anna 
Jack
```

I know I have to use some type of join and aggregate function here but not sure how to start.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can do it by using CTE ([result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vAEWDPGc3w3BW7gTEW8mPE/2))

```
with call_duration as (
select caller as phone_number, sum(duration) as duration from calls group by caller
union all
select callee as phone_number, sum(duration) as duration from calls group by callee
)
SELECT name
FROM phones p join call_duration cd on cd.phone_number = p.phone_number
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(duration) >= 10
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: that is a cool website! I think I forgot to mention that 'callee' in calls table should be accounted for when adding the duration. So we should add the duration for caller and callee, not just caller. If that makes sense?

Comment: Update done by using CTE. `If that makes sense?`: It's up to you to know if that makes sense.

Comment: I prefer CTES because i find it more readable

Answer (score 0):

***Option 1:using CTE***

with total_calls as(
select name as name, sum(duration) as total_duration
from phones p
right join calls c on p.phone_no = c.caller or p.phone_no = c.callee group by name
)
select
name
from total_calls
where total_duration >=10
order by name asc;

***Option 2:through subquery***

select name from
(select p.name as name, sum(duration) as total_duration
from phones p
join calls c on p.phone_no = c.caller or p.phone_no = c.callee group by name) as total_calls
where total_duration >=10
order by name asc;